# tmp_name de arquivos dentro de uma pasta zip

Tags: php, html, arquivo-zip

eu estou fazendo com código php que em que eu faço o upload de um arquivo zip e ele me retorna a lista dos nomes dos arquivos que há dentro do arquivo zip. Mas eu preciso que seja retornado a própria File da pasta zip, e nao apenas o nome, ou seja, quando eu der o `var_dump()`, ele deverá me retornar o `['tmp_name']`, assim como é feito com a pasta zip, porem desta vez de cada arquivo. Alguém pode me ajudar? Estou começando no PHP.

HTML:

```
<DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>CIC Project</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Test File .zip</h1>
        <form method="POST" action="testeZip.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="file" accept=".zip" id="arquivo" name="arquivo"><br>
            <button type="submit" id="buttonSubmit">POST</button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

PHP:

```
<?php

    if(isset($_POST)){
        $today = date("mY");
        $arquivoFile = $_FILES['arquivo'];
        var_dump($arquivoFile);
        $arquivo = zip_open($arquivoFile['tmp_name']);

        if($arquivo){
            while($lista_arquivos = zip_read($arquivo)){
                $newArchieves = $lista_arquivos.$_FILES['arquivo']['tmp_name'];
                echo "- Nome do Arquivo: ".zip_entry_name($lista_arquivos)."<br>";
                var_dump($newArchieves);
            }
            zip_close($arquivo);
        }

    }
?>
```

Resultado Atual:

```
array(5) { ["name"]=> string(26) "CONTASCEMIG_PBH_012019.zip" ["type"]=> string(28) "application/x-zip-compressed" ["tmp_name"]=> string(23) "C:\xampp\tmp\phpF60.tmp" ["error"]=> int(0) ["size"]=> int(5738) } - Nome do Arquivo: 266774672_PRODABEL_17022019_BT.xml
string(37) "Resource id #3C:\xampp\tmp\phpF60.tmp" - Nome do Arquivo: 266774672_PRODABEL_17022019_MT.xml
string(37) "Resource id #4C:\xampp\tmp\phpF60.tmp" - Nome do Arquivo: 356438293_BELOTUR_17022019_BT.xml
string(37) "Resource id #5C:\xampp\tmp\phpF60.tmp" - Nome do Arquivo: 849202935_SECFAZENDA_17022019_MT.xml
string(37) "Resource id #6C:\xampp\tmp\phpF60.tmp" - Nome do Arquivo: 938478493_LIMPEZAPUB_17022019_FR.xml
string(37) "Resource id #7C:\xampp\tmp\phpF60.tmp"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

o `tmp_name` é apenas o caminho temporário onde o arquivo fica salvo antes de você mover ele para a pasta que você quer, ele nâo é o original é apenas temporário. Se você quer o nome do arquivo zip que você enviou ele está no parametro `name` no caso `$arquivoFile['name']`

Para mover o arquivo tmp que você está enviando para uma outra pasta, você deve usar o `move_uploaded_file` mais info no doc do PHP http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.move-uploaded-file.php

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta clara, cHida, mas eu gostaria de saber mesmo é o nome dos arquivos dentro do .zip, e como chegar ate eles, por exemplo, ******nao quero fazer o download***** , mas suponha que eu queira fazer o download de um certo arquivo dentro da pasta zip... neste caso, eu precisaria chegar ate o certo arquivo, correto? como eu conseguiria chegar la ?

Comment: @SamuelMachado cara, você tem que abrir o zip por PHP extrair e pegar o arquivo que você quer. Só olhar a documentação do PHP para Zip e mover o arquivo com o move_uploaded_file para a pasta que você quer. Essa é a documentação que você precisa http://php.net/manual/en/class.ziparchive.php

Comment: Muito obrigado pelo apoio :)